# Content fallback Typo3 News 10.0.3

Tags: typo3, fallback

In a TYPO3 11.5.23 instance with News 10.0.3, I have added a content fallback through a hook in my custom TYPO3 extension. However, when I hide or disable a news record in the French language, the default record in German still appears in the list view, which is not desirable. Is it possible to disable the content fallback feature when the translated news records are hidden?

```
class Repository {
    `public function modify(array $params, NewsRepository $newsRepository) {`
        `$query = $params['query'];`
        `$query->getQuerySettings()->setLanguageOverlayMode(true);`
    }
}
```